# Android studio intent error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

Application name: envi

Main activity calls `screen1.java` and `screen1.java` calls `screen2` using `Intent`.
Im getting the following error:

```
Error:(24, 36) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/envi').
Error:(37, 36) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/envi').
```

This is what my androidmanifest.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kriti.envi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.kriti.envi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.kriti.envi.screen1"
                android:label="@string/envi" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.kriti.envi.actvityscreen2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_actvityscreen2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.kriti.envi.screen2"
                android:label="@string/envi" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
```

Comment: Have you put any string having name `envi` in in `/res/values/strings.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably caused because of missing string resource with key `envi`.

But you have other problems there. You have your `AndroidManifest.xml` wrong.

Tag `<intent-filter>` cannot contain tag `<activity>`, see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html).

It can contain only tags `<action>`, `<category>`, `<data>`. Tag `<activity>` can be placed only in tag `<application>`. So your application doesn't know any activities with names `com.example.kriti.envi.screen1` and `com.example.kriti.envi.screen2`.